# Slides appearing twice in DOM in Jssor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I've noticed that JSSOR duplicates the slides div and it's content in the DOM. This is probably done for a good reason and causes no issue whatsoever.

However, in order to implement some custom click functionality with a lightbox (Colorbox with grouping functionality), I needed to write a jquery selector for the individual images inside the slides. While that works, with the duplicate DOM I get the slides twice (the "correct" ones appearing last).

Is there a way to properly select only the "displayed" slides without the duplicates ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will investigate this issue later.

Comment: @jssor Also getting this, ATM I'm using only global selector, no IDs, but this has it's obvious limitations, please reply when found a solution.

Comment: There is an update, please download again.